# Issue with concat expression

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

Can someone explain what is happening here please, looking at the expression below, when I run the report the 'to' comes out as 'Ao'

```
="Date Range Selected: " & Format(Parameters!DateFrom.value, "yyyy/MM/dd" &" to " & Format(Parameters!DateTo.value, "yyyy/MM/dd"))
```

Date Range Selected: 2017/01/01 Ao 2017/04/19

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to closing brackets around the first format function and remove the second closing brackets at the end: ie....

```
="Date Range Selected: " & Format(Parameters!DateFrom.value, "yyyy/MM/dd") &" to " & Format(Parameters!DateTo.value, "yyyy/MM/dd")
```

Comment: It's better to not put it all in one expression. Use placeholders to hold the dynamic text - then you can format the placeholder and not use the format function, as well as see what the text says without having to edit the expression.  More information about placeholders: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/formatting-text-and-placeholders-report-builder-and-ssrs